# Finite Element model of Fourth order PDE in FreeFEM++

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, finite-element-method

I am attempting to finite element model the/a solution to the [Kuramoto-Sivashinsky equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuramoto%E2%80%93Sivashinsky_equation)

$$u_{t}+\nu u_{xxxx}+u_{xx}+uu_{x}=0 $$
with 1-periodic boundary condition
$$u(\cdot,0)=u_{0} $$

using the software FreeFem++.

Using [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40819-015-0068-0), I derived the following weak form of the equation:

$$ (u_t,\phi)+\nu(u_{xx},\phi_{xx})-(u_x,\phi_x)+(uu_x,\phi) = 0 $$

with $\phi \in H_{0}^2(I)$ as defined in the paper linked above.

I am having trouble translating this weak form into  FreeFEM++ code.  I am unsure how to handle the higher order term $\nu(u_{xx},\phi_{xx})$ and the nonlinear term $(uu_x,\phi)$.  Does anyone know how to represent this in FreeFEM? Will I need to discretize the weak form or is this good enough?  Can the command int2d be used to solve this problem?